# Options for devmgmt to open specific device

Tags: device-manager

I would like to use a Run command to not only open Device Manager (This command is devmgmt.msc), but also to open a specific branch or device within the UI (something like devmgmt.) is there any documentation for devmgmt options?

Answer (score 1):

Device Manager has no switches and will ignore any that are added on its
command-line (for example try `devmgmt.msc /?`).

If you wish to manipulate devices via the command line, you may use:

- [PNPUtil.exe](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/181.how-to-manage-device-drivers-with-command-line.aspx)
- [devcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)